# Android Studio handle SNAPSHOT dependencies

Tags: android, maven, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm having some troubles by using a SNAPSHOT dependency on Android Studio 3.0.1. I've also tried Android Studio 3.1, and the same issue remains.

I'm including the dependency in the following way:

```
dependencies {
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.cacheChangingModulesFor 0, 'seconds'
        resolutionStrategy.cacheDynamicVersionsFor 0, 'seconds'
    }
    implementation('com.example:lib:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT') { changing = true }
}
```

When a new version of the library is published, if I click the "Refresh all Gradle projects" icon, the app builds fine. However, Android Studio doesn't see any change made in the snapshot.

I've already tried to restart Android Studio and to invalidate its cache, without any difference.

How to make Android Studio aware of the changes?

Comment: Should the `configurations.all` block perhaps be outside the `dependencies` block?

Comment: I have the same problem, and I keep that block outside.

Comment: Do you use AS in offline mode? You can check it in `Preferences -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Gradle -> Global Gradle settings`. Offline work should be unchecked.

Comment: Note that the code you apply in "configurations.all" applies only to direct dependencies, if you are using transitive dependencies you should tell gradle to consider those as well. Here is an example of how this could be achieved: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/2317

Answer (score 4):

I have the same problem. So far, what works for me is to refresh the dependencies through the command line:

```
./gradlew clean --refresh-dependencies
```

After that, quit AS completely and open it again. I'll update my answer if I find something else.

Comment: This issue is absurd. Been using mavenLocal() to quickly publish updates to a library without having to use a remote repository, but this is broken since Studio 3.1 when using `android.enableBuildCache=true`.
Have you found any workaround to avoid having to refresh all dependencies?

Answer (score 2):

It is a bug in studio 3.1 -> https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/72614343

Fixed in latest Canary version (3.2)

Comment: I don't think this is the same issue. I'm using the 3.2 release channel build and I still have the same problem as the OP. AS's library/build cache simply doesn't seem to respect the gradle `resolutionStrategy`.